# Python - how to store multiple lists in one list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, signal-processing, spectrogram

this is the output of multiple lists and i want to store them in one list or array

```
(array([[  1.52494154e+11,   1.52811638e+11,   1.52565040e+11, ...,
              1.47778892e+11,   1.46781213e+11,   1.46678951e+11],
           [  7.69589176e+10,   7.73638333e+10,   7.76935891e+10, ...,
              7.48498747e+10,   7.40088248e+10,   7.40343108e+10],
           [  6.32683585e+04,   1.58170271e+06,   6.11287648e+06, ...,
              5.06690834e+05,   3.31360693e+05,   7.04757400e+05],
           ..., 
           [  7.79589127e+05,   8.09843763e+04,   2.52907491e+05, ...,
              2.48520301e+05,   2.11734697e+05,   2.50917758e+05],
           [  9.41199946e+05,   4.98371406e+05,   1.29328139e+06, ...,
              2.56729806e+05,   3.45253951e+05,   3.51932417e+05],
           [  4.36846676e+05,   1.24123764e+06,   9.20694394e+05, ...,
              8.35807658e+04,   8.36986905e+05,   3.57807267e+04]]), array([   0.     ,    3.90625,    7.8125 ,   11.71875,   15.625  ,
             19.53125,   23.4375 ,   27.34375,   31.25   ,   35.15625,
             39.0625 ,   42.96875,   46.875  ,   50.78125,   54.6875 ,
             58.59375,   62.5    ,   66.40625,   70.3125 ,   74.21875,
             78.125  ,   82.03125,   85.9375 ,   89.84375,   93.75   ,
             97.65625,  101.5625 ,  105.46875,  109.375  ,  113.28125,
            117.1875 ,  121.09375,  125.     ,  128.90625,  132.8125 ,
            136.71875,  140.625  ,  144.53125,  148.4375 ,  152.34375,
            156.25   ,  160.15625,  164.0625 ,  167.96875,  171.875  ,
            175.78125,  179.6875 ,  183.59375,  187.5    ,  191.40625,
            195.3125 ,  199.21875,  203.125  ,  207.03125,  210.9375 ,
            214.84375,  218.75   ,  222.65625,  226.5625 ,  230.46875,
            234.375  ,  238.28125,  242.1875 ,  246.09375,  250.     ,
            253.90625,  257.8125 ,  261.71875,  265.625  ,  269.53125,
            273.4375 ,  277.34375,  281.25   ,  285.15625,  289.0625 ,
            292.96875,  296.875  ,  300.78125,  304.6875 ,  308.59375,
            312.5    ,  316.40625,  320.3125 ,  324.21875,  328.125  ,
            332.03125,  335.9375 ,  339.84375,  343.75   ,  347.65625,
            351.5625 ,  355.46875,  359.375  ,  363.28125,  367.1875 ,
            371.09375,  375.     ,  378.90625,  382.8125 ,  386.71875,
            390.625  ,  394.53125,  398.4375 ,  402.34375,  406.25   ,
            410.15625,  414.0625 ,  417.96875,  421.875  ,  425.78125,
            429.6875 ,  433.59375,  437.5    ,  441.40625,  445.3125 ,
            449.21875,  453.125  ,  457.03125,  460.9375 ,  464.84375,
            468.75   ,  472.65625,  476.5625 ,  480.46875,  484.375  ,
            488.28125,  492.1875 ,  496.09375,  500.     ]), array([  1.28000000e-01,   2.56000000e-01,   3.84000000e-01, ...,
             1.41529600e+03,   1.41542400e+03,   1.41555200e+03]), <matplotlib.image.AxesImage object at 0x000002161A78F898>)
```

this my code, tese multiple lists comes from the spectrogram of three axis sensor data, to calculate the spectrogram i have calculate the magnitude of the three axis.. what i want is to save the spectrogram output in a more efficient way to use it as an input in another model as a text file

```
dataset = np.loadtxt("trainingdatasetMAG.txt", delimiter=",")
X = dataset[:,0:6]
Y = dataset[:,6]
fake_size = 1415684
time = np.arange(fake_size)/1000 # 1kHz
base_freq = 2 * np.pi * 100
magnitude = dataset[:,5]
plt.title('xyz_magnitude')
ls=(plt.specgram(magnitude, Fs=1000))
```

Comment: You already have an array of lists

Comment: How do you want the output to be different than what you already have?

Comment: the output have multiple lists and i want the output to be in one list only

Comment: Looks like you have a `tuple` with 3 arrays and an object.  What's the shape of the arrays?

Comment: when i write for example a = np.array(ls); print(a.shape) it gets me the following output (4,)

Comment: That's just turning the tuple into an object dtype array with 4 items.  I want the shape of `ls[0]`, `ls[1]` etc.  The first looks like it is 2d, the other 2 are 1d..  The forth is not any array.

Comment: how to to get each shape of these lists

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to flatten the list. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python), repeated here.

```
newlist = [item for sublist in mainlist for item in sublist]
```